# Adding svg element using jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, attributes, append

I am trying to create a graph using svg element and then appending a rect element for each bar of the graph in a loop.

How do I pass the "moveBar" variable into the .append statement to adjust the width attribute of the rect element?

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ulEmployees = $('#ulEmployees');
            var moveBar = 0;

            $('#btn').click(function () {
                $.ajax('api/AnnualPowerInterruptions', {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        ulEmployees.empty();
                        $('#graphData2').append("<svg id=mySVG class='chart' width='500' height='500'></div>");
                        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            var name = val.year;
                            ulEmployees.append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
                            $('#mySVG').append("<g transform='translate (100, 0)'><rect width=moveBar 'height='40' style='fill:red'> </rect> <text x='-50' y='30' fill='red'> blue </text></g>");
                            window.alert(moveBar);
                            moveBar = moveBar + 50;
                        });
                        $("#graphData2").html($("#graphData2").html())
                    }

                });

            });
```

```html
            <div id="graphData2">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to assign variable value to your rect tag like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ulEmployees = $("#ulEmployees");
  var moveBar = 0;

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax("api/AnnualPowerInterruptions", {
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        ulEmployees.empty();
        $("#graphData2").append(
          "<svg id=mySVG class='chart' width='500' height='500'></div>"
        );
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
          var name = val.year;
          ulEmployees.append("<li>" + name + "</li>");
          $("#mySVG").append(
            `<g transform='translate (100, 0)'><rect width=${moveBar} 'height='40' style='fill:red'> </rect> <text x='-50' y='30' fill='red'> blue </text></g>`
          );
          window.alert(moveBar);
          moveBar = moveBar + 50;
        });
        $("#graphData2").html($("#graphData2").html());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="graphData2">
</div>
```